Blender switches individual origins to median when several faces selected
I'm trying to rotate individual faces in an edge loop, along the normal and individual origins. It works if I manually select a few faces, randomly. However, if I try selecting several with the C tool, or the full edge loop, it starts rotating along the median point and ignores the individual origins.
Why is that? is it any kind of weird optimization? How can I get around this?

I guess what you mean is when you select connected faces. The Individual Origins does (and can) only work on single separate faces or mesh islands.
Single faces:

Mesh islands (selected faces with unselected surrounding faces):

The reason for this seemingly "broken" individual origins function: take a simple example like two connected faces. If you would try to rotate them individually, what exactly should happen with the mutual edge which between them belongs to both?

I have split the faces to show the dilemma: rotating them for example counter-clockwise would mean the top vertex of the edge would move up with one face and down with the other, same goes for the bottom vertex. But since they are not split, they cannot do both.

If they would keep their center position between the two necessary positions, this would result in the faces not being rotated, but distorted.

That is why connected faces are treated as "individual" parts and since they have to be rotated together, their median point is used as pivot. But it is still different than the actual Median Point option, because with Individual Origins multiple mesh islands will all be rotating around their own individual median points, while with Median Point all islands will rotate around their mutual center.
Of course in the first examples the surrounding faces get distorted as well, but that does not count because they are unselected and Blender does not really "care" what happens to them during rotation, that's "collateral damage" so to speak. This changes only if Proportional Editing gets enabled.
